# Skype web page embed - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, bots, botframework

I built a bot last week and embedded this on a web page using the generated Skype embed code from the MS Bot website. It was tested numerous times and there were no issues.

I've attempted to access the page this morning however the bot is failing to load and an error is being returned to the console. The issue is with the SDK script (https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.js)

[image: here]

Comment: It seems `document.body` is `null`. But without further information, it is very hard to find the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

The JS currently provided by the MS Bot Framework calls https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/0.12.2/ which returns no data, hence the null error.

I have resolved this by switching the JS script in my HTML for https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js as provided by the Skype dev website.

I assume this will be updated by MS shortly as the original script was working on Friday.